# Angular close modal dialog when pressing escape in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, sharepoint-2013

I have the following directive attached to an element that closes a SharePoint 2013 modal dialog when the user presses the `esc` key.

```
    app.directive("closeDialog", function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            document.onkeypress = function(e) {
                var dialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog();
                if(dialog || dialog != null) {
                    SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel, null);
                }
                scope.$apply();
            };
        }
    };
});
```

It works in IE and Firefox, but not in Chrome or Safari. Any suggestions?

Comment: Even handling can vary between browsers. Using a library like jQuery helps handle all the nuances. Is using JQuery an option here?

Comment: I can use jquery if I have to...just trying to see if it will work with native angular if possible.

Comment: is that the whole code? i don't think i see the escape key bit, and that's usually the cross browser issue with key events

Comment: So what would the escape key bit be? if(e.keyCode === 27) or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forgot to update with the answer. `$document` was the answer.

```
app.directive("closeDialog", function($document) {
    function closeModalDialog(scope) {
        var dialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog();
        if(dialog != null) {
            SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel, null);
        }
        scope.$apply();
    }
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $document.on("keydown", function(e) {
                closeModalDialog(scope);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: You need to remove the listener on destroy as well